# magento category page not displaying after flush magento cache

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, cache

I am using magento 1.9, I have customized theme, I did flush magento cache and all my product stop showing. If i change the theme name in magento category it start showing again. What is the reason behind it ??

Comment: What are the customization you have done please paste code here.

Comment: theme Code is very big and present in app/design/frontend/theme almost all files are changed. But it was working absolutely fine but when i did flush magento cache from admin panel it stopped showing product.

Comment: @shilpisharma, try reindexing and after reindexation flush your cache and see if its working.